# why locking stategies is used in hibernate, while DBMS internally handel it?

Tags: hibernate

locking stategies used by most DBMS internally to implement transaction isolation. why in hibernate we use
locking strategies?

Comment: The answer is: for finer-grain control than the transaction isolation levels give you by default

Comment: thanks, could you please explain in detail?

Answer (score 1):

Explicit pessimistic locks give you more control than transaction isolation level. Consider the following method:

```java
@Transactional(isolation = READ_COMMITED)
public void update() {
    Order order = em.find(Order.class, 5L); //as far as order is concerned, according to our business logic, we're fine with READ_COMMITED, we don't care is some other transaction updates shippingAddress, for instance
    order.setStatus(COMPLETED);
    OrderStatistics statistics = em.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Orderstatistics WHERE month = :month")
        .setParameter("month", LocalDate.now().getMonth());
        .setLockMode(PESSIMISTIC_WRITE) // we're very much not ok with some other transaction trying to increment completedOrders in the meantime, so we apply more stringent control
        .getSingleResult();
    statistics.incrementCompletedOrders();
}
```

Optimistic locks, in turn, enable you to use optimistic locking, a synchronization mechanism that is not available in most RDBMSes at all.